# Can't get Chain "MASQUERADE" to work on WSL2 Kernel

Tags: kernel, iptables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to build custom Kernel for my specific requirement where I need the chain `MASQUERADE` to be available. I'm using https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel to build my kernel.

I've set all the config I could find for `MASQ` and `MASQUERADE` to `y`.

No matter how I build the Kernel, every time I run `iptables -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 10.33.33.1 -j MASQUERADE --wait` I get `iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Chain 'MASQUERADE' does not exist`. Same happens with `iptables-legacy`.

I can't load any custom built kernel module either using `insmod` or `modprobe`.

Anyone got it to work or knows how to make it work? I tried building a Linux Kernel from kernel.org but as it turns out, it's not usable with WSL.

Comment: I tried it on `5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2` on my Ubuntu server 20.04.4 WSL under windows 10 and it worked fine.

Comment: @DougSmythies That's good - It makes me more confident that the answer I'm posting will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The core issue here is that Ubuntu 22.04 now defaults to `nf_tables` instead of the legacy `iptables`.  The syntax and default rules are quite different.

While I'd encourage you to look into the new syntax for `nf_tables` (since we'll need to know it eventually), you can likely solve this in the short term by falling back to `iptables-legacy` via:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

Note that it's possible that other rules are missing in `nf_tables` that your rule relies on, so it may require additional configuration.

Update note:  I just noticed that `nftables` isn't enabled in the currently *released* WSL2 kernel.  It's available in a new preview release 5.15.57.1 (available bundled with the [0.65.3](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.65.3) preview) released yesterday.  So currently, the fallback to legacy `iptables` is probably the only solution short of upgrading or compiling a custom kernel.